# Node.js Express - Handle Error Differently Based on Error Type

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, error-handling, handlebars.js

A few details... I'm using Express 4, Node 0.12.2 and Express-Handlebars as my view engine.

I'm trying to render a partial via AJAX call and would like to handle different errors types differently. The err object passed on the callback invocation doesn't seem to have much useful info to work with, just an error message. Is there something I'm missing here?

```js
// Search (Partial)
router.get('/search-products', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('partials/search/products', {layout: 'ajax'}, function(err, html){
        if(err) {
            // return res.status(404).send(err);
            // return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe something like this?
if(res.statusCode == 404) res.status(404).send(err);

Comment: I don't believe the error object has a status code, but I'll double check.

Comment: @rtc11 That would check if the response already has the status code set to 404 and then it would set it to 404 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error object isn't going to have a status code because it's an error object generated by the view engine. If that error is populated you can pretty much assume it's a 500 error because the view engine failed to compile a view for some reason.

For example, if you're using Jade, that error object will be populated if you try to have Jade compile a template that has invalid Jade syntax. The error there is never going to be HTTP related which means it's always just a server-side error and status code 500 should suffice.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing like you said and sending back a 500 code, but I wanted to double check if there was any way to differentiate between a compilation error vs something like a missing template. It doesn't seem like there is. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, I think just the message is the only way to tell. A 404 code is usually about a missing route rather than a missing file these days because the file is assumed to exist and is considered a server error if it doesn't, but if you really want a route to be able to return a 404 in the case of a missing template, simply check for it manually first using [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) :)